# jQuery selecting a forms radio buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have a form and I use this `document.forms["form-0"].answerN[0];` to select a specific radio button, however I could not manage to do it with jQuery.

I tried `$('forms["form-0"]')` and `$('forms[0]')` to get to the form but it didn't work, and both do work using the long path..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can access like this ( jQuery v1.6)

```
$('form > input:radio').prop('id');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ZF27B/2)

### update

As you can aceess **form** by `name` or `id` attribute also like this

```
 $('form[name="firstForm"] > input:radio').prop('id');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ZF27B/4/)

Comment: thanx for the demo, but is there a way to use this with a form ID or name? it tried `$('form-0 > input:radio').prop('id');` `$('forms[0] > input:radio').prop('id');` `$('"form-0" > input:radio').prop('id');` and none worked...

Comment: obviously you can use with form `name` and `id` whatever. see my updated answer :)

Comment: also you can access first form by `$("form").eq(0)`

Comment: You can access form just by index  `$("form").eq(1).find('input:radio').prop('id');` // will access second form as index start from  **0**

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ZF27B/5/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: `$("form input:radio")`

For further assistance follow [this](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) link.

Comment: is there a way to use form ID/name instead of just `form`?

Comment: @IlyaD  `$("#formId input:radio:")`  should do.

Answer (score 1):

form-0 is the name of the form. You have to write something like

```
$('form[name=form-0]') to select the form.
```

to get the radio button you will have to move further to use children

so

```
$('form[name=form-0]').children('radio[name=answerN]:first-child')
```

hopefully this should work

Comment: you don't know if will stay a child or become a descendant in his code, so you should use "find()" instead of "children()" $("form[name='form-0']").find(":radio[name='answerN']")

Comment: also write  `"` like `name="form-o"` and `name="answerN"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" value="0" class="radio" id="firstRadioButton" /> Value
</form>
```

you can select elements by their id:

selects the radio button

```
$("#firstRadioButton)
```

selects the form

```
$("#myForm")
```

Or select all radio buttons:

```
$("#myForm input.radio").each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

And without using IDs:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" value="1" /> Value 1 <br />
    <input type="radio" value="2" /> Value 2 <br />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($("form").first().find("input:radio").first().val());
```

Example: Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ks57/)

Comment: thanx, that's a nice solution, using IDs, but isn't there a way to shorten `document.forms["form-0"].answerN[0]` without using IDs? It seems all the other answer make a longer code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to reach all the forms in your page:

```
$('forms').each(function(id){
    console.log(id,$(this));
});
```